# Can't make ready and resize functions work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 containers placed side by side (floating). Both of these containers have multiples forms generated dinamically and I can’t know which one will be the highest.

So I use a simple `script` to calculate both `divs`height and apply the highest to both. Easy enough and working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var height = Math.max($(".left").outerHeight(),$(".right").outerHeight());
    $(".left").height(height);
    $(".right").height(height);
});
```

The  forms inside are responsive, so it will be displayed in 3, 2 or 1 column depending on window width. Simple and easy `css`:

```
.form {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    padding-right:20px;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .form {
    width:100%;
    } 
}
```

My problema is that I can’t seem to make the script work BOTH at resize and at ready function when the page is loaded and run the script anytime the user resize the window manually.

So far I have tried the solutions I have found here around but none Works so far and I have no idea why. I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
         var height = Math.max($(".left").outerHeight(), $(".right").outerHeight());
            $(".left").height(height);
            $(".right").height(height);
    }).resize();        

});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).on('resize',myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    var height = Math.max($(".left").outerHeight(),$(".right").outerHeight());
    $(".left").height(height);
    $(".right").height(height);
}
```

and

```
var callback = function () {
  var height = Math.max($(".left").outerHeight(),$(".right").outerHeight());
    $(".left").height(height);
    $(".right").height(height);
};

$(document).ready(callback);
$(window).resize(callback);
```

But while still working when reloading the window, resizing when the containers grow (under 800px) doesn’t run the script (or the height value doesn’t change).

I’m not an expert at javascript / jquery so probably I’m missing something basic but after many hours I can’t find any solution.

Here is a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e2rdq2hu/2/)** with an example with the original `script`. Any Little help would be greetly apreciated.

Comment: I expect that while resizing the script to the the same as when the page loads. check both div's height and applied the highest to both. Basically when the windows get smaller than 800px and the forms inside the divs change the position both divs height increase wuite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are handling the resize is correct, the issue is that you have already set the `height` of both of the `div`s previously, therefore they are no longer expanding/contracting to the size of their contents. I.E if the `height` of the `div`s was set to 286 on load the `Math.max` calculation will be using 286 when the window is resized.

To fix, reset the `height` before you calculate which is bigger:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".left, .right").height('auto');
  var height = Math.max($(".left").outerHeight(), $(".right").outerHeight());
  $(".left, .right").height(height);
}).resize();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.form {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .form {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <div class="form">
    <p>form</p>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <p>form</p>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <p>form</p>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <p>form</p>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="form">
    <p>form</p>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <p>form</p>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's is EXACTLY what I need. Thank very much,

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.